# sample todolist for xamarin forms(droid) using azure mobile apps

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed the tutorials [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/) and I was able to post/get from angular to the api and vice versa but I can't find a sample code for the xamarin forms. I would like to run it on android. I got a sample code but it seems to be obsolete and has runtime error.

If anyone has any resources on connecting xamarin forms (droid) to the api apps, please share.

Comment: you will use azure mobile services. did you already check this ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started/

Comment: @Aravind Yes, but sadly when I try to run the sample source code, it has runtime error. Isn't `azure mobile services` already deprecated. Is it still applicable in app services?

Comment: it is part for app services.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/